# How to Iterate 10 element each time from a Iterator<String> of size 100

Tags: java, loops, iterator

I have an iterator of a string of size 100. I want to get 10 elements each time and pass them into another function.
Is there any method/way other than making conditions inside the loop to count 10 element?

Comment: Collect the 10 elements in an sublist by calling the iterator 10 times in an for loop. Then pass that to your function

Answer (score 2):

It depends what you need to do with them but the way the question is written it seems you want to process ten items at a time.

```
Iterator<String> it = ... ;
List<String> nextBatch = nextBatchOf(it, 10);

// do something with nextBatch
```

and the method for getting the next batch of elements

```
List<String> nextBatchOf(Iterator<String> it, int size) {
    List<String> batch = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < size && it.hasNext(); i++) {
        batch.add(it.next());
    }
    return batch;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can you standart Arrays API:

```
    int step = 10;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i ++){
        anotherFunction(Arrays.copyOfRange(source, i * step, (i + 1) * step));
    }
```

Comment: (in case this is an array and he wants copies of the data)